# Stringify BigInt as a number instead of string

Tags: javascript

Since `JSON.stringify` does not support BigInts, a common suggestion is to patch `toJSON` into its prototype or use a replacer function to the likes of `(k, v) => typeof v === 'bigint' ? v.toString() : v`. The problem is, this stringifies BigInts as strings and not numbers `{ foo: 123n }` becomes `{ "foo": "123" }` instead of `{ "foo": 123 }`.

I have a requirement to produce a payload for an API that expects a number, and that number can exceed the largest safe integer possible in JS. Is there any way to do that, besides building the string myself (or stripping out the quotes afterwards)?

Comment: JSON is JSON, if you change it, it's not JSON any more

Comment: `that number can exceed the largest safe integer possible in JS` - if this is an issue, when the client uses `JSON.parse` on your result, you'll lose precision

Comment: @qrsngky: It’s not necessarily the case that the JSON is being *parsed* by JavaScript.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Not an issue here.

Comment: You'll need https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-parse-with-source

Comment: If it's fine for you to use third-party library, and your concern is only building a string (not parsing it), you may want to use the `stringify` in the [lossless-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lossless-json/v/1.0.3) package.

Comment: @qrsngky it's only an issue if Javascript is doing the parsing. Any language that parses numbers into int64 wouldn't have a problem. I only need to stringify the object on JS side I find it odd that the replacer function can only output quoted strings.

Comment: Eventually we were able to convince the API vendor to change their specification, but it doesn't sound right that they have to adapt their product to a gimmick of a language they're not using.

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t have this built in, but there’s really nothing wrong with using a library for it (consider: using a library is what you would have to do in most other languages) – especially an implementation of the proposal Bergi linked.

Answer (score -1):

I would add some kind of unique token to the bigint string, then strip the quotes and token as a whole after stringify:

```js
const data = { foo: 123456789012345678901234567890n, bar: 1234567890 };

const json = JSON.stringify(data, 
  (k, v) => typeof v === 'bigint' ? 'BIGINT_' + v : v
).replace(/"BIGINT_(\d+)"/g, '$1');

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you are looking for, Javascript cannot natively parse  BigInt in JSON, but there are ways to work around that with altering `JSON.parse()` from the [MDN BigInt Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#use_within_json).

If your number is less than 2^53-1, then using `Number(big_int)` would be ideal. You can test for this with:

```js
var x = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // 2^53 - 1
if (!isNaN(Number(x)) && Number.isSafeInteger(x)) {
  var number_int = Number(x)
}
```

If you really need to have the BigInt as in numeric form without the double quotes this is a quick and dirty way using string replacement. It replaces and stores BigInt values in a list before `JSON.stringify()` and then replacing the stub values with the numeric BigInt:

```js
var my_object = {
  key1: 24345354355435435454,
  key2: 24345354355435435454,
  key3: 53354545,
};

const big_json = json_obj => {
  var counter = 0;
  var key_holder = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(my_object)) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(value)) && !Number.isSafeInteger(value)) {
      key_holder.push(value);
      my_object[key] = 'XXX' + String(counter);
      counter++;
    }
  }
  var json_string = JSON.stringify(my_object);

  for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    json_string = json_string.replace('"XXX' + String(i) + '"', key_holder[i]);
  }
  return json_string;
};

console.log(big_json(my_object))
```